# ActionController::UnknownFormat with respond_to js in Action:Create

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, respond-to

my route.rb

```
  post 'home/create'
  get  'home/create'
```

my HomeController

```
   def create
       @review_n = Review.create(review_params)
       if @review_n.errors.empty?
         respond_to do |format|
           format.js { render 'create', locals: {review_name: @review_n.review_n, review_body: @review_n.review_body} }
         end
       else
         render 'index'
       end
    end
```

my create.js.erb

```
    $(function() {
      $(".wrap-body").append("<div> tmp </div>");
    });
```

rails say:   ActionController::UnknownFormat in HomeController#create

I want send data in my html.erb without reload page. Help me, please!

UPD:

my html.rb

```
      <%= form_tag home_create_path, :method => 'post', :remote => true do %>
            <%= text_area_tag  'review[review_body]', nil  %>
            <%= text_field_tag 'review[review_name]', nil %>
            <%= submit_tag 'send' %>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you also add the logs?

Comment: Can you also change your routes to `post 'home/create' => 'home#create'`? Why do you need `get 'home/create'`.

Comment: My mistake (( in my HomeController: review_n.review_n to review_n.review_name

Answer (score 0):

Is your code hitting the `render 'index'` call that is outside of the `respond_to` block?

Normally you would put all `render` calls inside the `respond_to` block, so it's obvious that all paths of your logic can respond to all expected formats:

```
def create
  @review_n = Review.create(review_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @review_n.errors.empty?
      format.js { render 'create', locals: {review_name: @review_n.review_n, review_body: @review_n.review_body} }
    else
      format.js { render 'index' }
    end
  end
end
```

This requires having both a `create.js.erb` and an `index.js.erb` (for the error case).

Also, as @sahil recommended, your routes.rb should not declare `get 'home/create'` - this action modifies data, so it isn't safe to make it accessible via `GET`.